# Installing Android Marshmallow through network boot (Serva Software) - Error Occured

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to network boot (PXE) android OS using [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html);
I got the following error:

`INITRD_N16.3.GZ does not support kernel=4.0.9-android-vmi`

Booting OS : Android Marshmallow
Serva Version : 3.0

Note: I am able to network boot other versions of Android ( eg: kitkat, lollipop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Serva's website

https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html

the complementary [INITRD_N16.3.GZ](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/download/INITRD_N16.3.GZ) has been tested net booting `android-x86-4.4-r5.iso`

If you are trying to net boot a different architecture or a newer version you
need an updated INITRD; just wait until it is made available for download.

Comment: Yeah just now figured it out, INITRD_N16.3.GZ  is for 32 bit, but the android ISO is 64 bit.

Comment: same INITRD_N16.3.GZ  file works like a charm for Android-x86(Lollipop). Thanks dude .. :)

Comment: if you found the answer correct please accept it; it'll help other people having the same problem.